# Enabling Gitlab LFS on Synology NAS

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs, synology

I want to enable Gitlab LFS on my Synology DS 918+. To install Gitlab I used the official Synology/Gitlab package from the Synology Package Manager.

As you can read, LFS needs to be enabled in the gitlab.yaml (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/lfs/lfs_administration.html)

But I can't find my gitlab.yaml on my Synology NAS when i SSH into it.

I hope you can help me. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, what you want: do you need a git server, where you want to push your code to? Is it relevant that you use Synology?

Comment: Yes, need a local git server to push my code to. I have a Synology NAS and want to use that. There is a Gitlab package which I can install from the Synology Package Manager. This works fine, except that I cant enable Git LFS (Large File System). For doing that I need to edit my gitlab.yaml and I can't find that!

Comment: Does that help https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/gitlab.yml.html?

Comment: Did you manage to make LFS working on synology NAS ? Even if the repository is marked **Git LFS status: enabled** on gitlab I cannot push to it.

Answer (score 0):

//after doing SSH into your NAS, run the following command

docker container ls

//the first column is 'CONTAINER ID'
//copy the container ID that corresponds to the primary gitlab container, (the IMAGE column should read something like 'synology/gitlab:11.11.9')

//then you can run this line, but replace 'mycontainer' with the container ID you saw //from the previous command

docker exec -t -i mycontainer /bin/bash

//now you are in the actual container file system
//then you can use the following command to locate the config file

find . -name gitlab.yaml

//then use vim or nano to edit that file
//the following example shows where I found the yaml file but your path may be //different

sudo nano ./config/gitlab.yml

//hope that helps! :)